# How do I un-initialize an object in C++?

Tags: c++, class, object, initialization

I'm not 100% certain I worded the title for this right so here's what I want to be able to do...

I have a class that gets defined like so...

```
class Animal
{
public:
    Animal() : m_name("New Animal")
    {
    }

    Animal(const std::string& name) : m_name(name)
    {
    }

    Animal(const Animal& animal) : m_name(animal.name)
    {
    }

private:
    const std::string name;
};
```

I then initialize an object of this class like so...

```
Animal* m_animal = new Animal("Leroy");
```

At some point in my program, the user will click a button that will cause m_animal to become empty. Meaning that the pet named Leroy should not longer exist..

I assumed I could use delete m_animal, but once I call this I can no longer use m_animal without causing a memory allocation error.

So I guess my question is...
Would me using the following code cause a memory leak since the pet named Leroy was not deleted... and if so what are alternatives on how to get this done?

```
m_pet = NULL;
```

The entire process would look like this...

```
Animal* m_animal = new Animal("Leroy");
Animal* m_animal2 = new Animal("Boo");
std::cout << m_animal.name << endl;
m_animal = NULL;
m_animal = new Animal(m_animal2);
std::cout << m_animal.name << endl;
```

Comment: Yes that is a memory leak

Comment: use `m_animal->name` rather than `m_animal.name` because its a pointer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *do* want to use `delete m_animal;`. You can do this:

```
std::cout << m_animal.name << endl;
delete m_animal;
m_animal = new Animal(m_animal2);
std::cout << m_animal.name << endl;
```

After calling `delete m_animal`, you can no longer use *what `m_animal` pointed to*, but you can certainly use the `m_animal` pointer again.

Comment: You should set m_animal to nullptr/NULL after the delete or you could end up in a double delete situation. The OP should probably use shared_ptr.

Comment: @James: There is no problem with the code as I have given it; in this case `m_animal` is assigned a new value immediately after the `delete`. However, if you're not going to give the pointer a new value straight away, then yes it would be useful to assign `NULL`.

Comment: Worked great, only question I have now is...  
So in my about example, when I create a new animal from m_animal2... If I no longer use m_animal2, do I have to use delete m_animal2?

Comment: @Ricky: That depends. Do you want to keep `m_animal2` around for any reason? If not, then you can delete it. Your copy constructor makes a *copy* of the name, and doesn't keep a reference to the copied object. (Also, I think you'd have to use `new Animal(*m_animal2)` to properly invoke the copy constructor without a compile error.)

Comment: @GregHewgill If the `new` throws, though, you may get a double delete.

Comment: @GregHewgill: if you `delete` a pointer and not set it to NULL right away, then go to `new` an assignment to that pointer and `new` throws, the pointer will be left with its original `delete`d value.  Later code could then check the pointer and try to `delete` it again, thus the double-delete issue. So, if you are going to use raw `new`/`delete` calls, you should use `delete m_animal; m_animal = NULL; m_animal = new Animal(...);` as a safety catch against `new` failing.

Comment: @GregHewgill as others have pointed this may not be exception safe. There is a problem

Comment: In the OP's example code, there is no `try` block and the pointers are declared in the same scope as the `new`/`delete`. As such, there is no possibility of exception handling causing a double delete, because by the time any exception is caught, the pointer in question is well out of scope. Having said that, yes, of course you're all correct, the addition of exception handling does require additional considerations to be applied to code construction. Similarly, so do multithreading and shared memory, two other things that could invalidate my example. But those aren't part of the question.

Answer (score 2):

You could just add a `clear` member function that (for example) sets the name to an empty string. This means "Leroy" no longer exists, but an `Animal` in a valid state exists, so you can use it to hold some other animal without deleting the old one and allocating a new one.

This, however, still leaves an Animal object--just one that doesn't have a name. If you want to separate allocation from creation/destruction of the objects in the memory, you can allocate raw memory with `operator new`, then use a placement new to create an object in that memory. When you want to destroy the object, you can directly invoke its destructor, which will truly destroy the object (but leave the memory allocated).

When you're done with the memory, you can use `operator delete` to delete the memory.

Aside: this is pretty much what `std::vector`, for one example, does with its memory block. While it's probably *more* useful when you're dealing with multiple objects, there's nothing particularly wrong with doing it for a single object either.

Aside #2: in most cases, you don't need (or really want) to use `new` or `delete` directly as you've shown above. In quite a few cases, you can use an `std::shared_ptr` or `std::unique_ptr` instead, with `std::make_shared` or `std::make_unique` to allocate the object.

Comment: My bad - I did not read your paragraph 1 properly ... sorry about the duplicate answer.  +1 Great minds and all that.

Comment: But if you choose to use this method, remember that you must not have given the object anywhere else, since reusing the object for another animal will also change the object that is pointed to elsewhere. So especially as a beginner it might be better to just use new objects every time.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes (but not for this mcve), it is simpler to use an init() method.

Though I prefer the initialization list such as you have used here (after the ctor), you will sometimes run into system start up sequence options where the ctor parameter is *not* yet available and thus can not be filled in by the ctor. This is a particular problem when two or more instances (of same or different class) have pointers to the other (as in working and protect hw control)

So, you might consider the following, which solves sequencing and mutual dependency challenges by providing an  init() method.

```
class Animal
{
public:
    Animal()
    {
        init("New Animal")
    }

    Animal(const std::string name)
    {
        init(name);
    }

    Animal(const Animal& animal)
    {
        init(animal.m_name); 
    }

    void init(std::string name)
    {
       m_name.erase(); // clear the previous attribute 
       //           (not really needed here, but included for clarity)
       m_name = name;  // fill in new attribute 

       // and continue with both clear (when needed) and init's 
       // of all the other data attributes 
       // in an order similar to the initialization list.
       // note that the compiler won't be able to notify you
       // of out of order initialization issues.
   }

private:
    const std::string name;
};
```

---

So, is init() good for anything else?

You asked

> how do I un-initialize an object.

In this case, you can simply use "init(...)" to simultaneously

a) clear out the previous state info (when necessary)

b) initialize the state info as if newly created

and

c) **avoid** the relatively costly delete and new of the other approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you create an object with the `new` operator, then you need to delete it with the `delete` operator.

```
Animal* animal = new Animal( "Pig" );

// Using the animal ...

delete animal;
animal = nullptr;
```

You need to use the `new` - `delete` pair to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: So in my about example, when I create a new animal from m_animal2... If I no longer use m_animal2, do I have to use delete m_animal2?

Comment: Yes, when you don't want to use any more use need to delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Since these two are pointers to Animal class. This should work too:

```
std::cout << m_animal->name << endl;
m_animal = m_animal2;
std::cout << m_animal->name << endl;
```

No need to allocate memory for an animal third time, even if one of them gets deleted before, its inefficient code. Then you should delete only one of these pointers and set them both to `nullptr`. Using an `std::shared_ptr` may be a more robust solution though.